# Вывод информации из базы данных в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть база данных

```
id,номер,ширина,высота,комментарий
```

Делаю форму в Tkinter два поля и кнопка поиска. При нажатии на кнопку поиска выводится окно с надписью `Alert`. Как я понял либо данные не в `int` попадают и тем самым не считываются либо вообще не долетают до кинтера. Без GUI работает все правильно.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
root = Tk()
root.title("Подбор щеток AEZ.")
root.geometry('600x400')

def printRecords():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('brush.db')
    cur = connection.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE width = ?  AND height = ?", (wi.get(), he.get()))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    messagebox.showinfo("", results)
    print(results)

Label(root, text = "Введите ширину и высоту:      ").grid()


wi = Entry()
he = Entry()
wi.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
he.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
root.update()

SearchButton = Button(root, text="Search", command=printRecords)
SearchButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У меня все работает, правда на картинке в коде запроса к БД изменил AND на OR, чтобы меньше текста вводить ))) https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJXJh.jpg

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш комментарий очень помог- я понял что данные у меня не те в таблице хранятся=)) Пересоздал базу с явным указанием что ячейки таблицы текстовые и все заработало.